# compare increase rate of group x and y that change over time in R

Tags: r

*if you have two groups of data "x" and "y" change over "time" , compare if the increase rate of "x" and "y" over time is same or not.*

My question is how do it start this problem, what are the steps that I needed to do? 
This problem has been bothering me for the past week and I have no idea how to approach it. your help is appreciated. 
I will be working in R for this project

What I did is `plot(x~time)` and `plot(y~time)` both X and Y are linear they go from bottom left to top right of the chart. From this how do I tell R to find the increase rate from X to y?

Comment: this may not be the best forum to ask such a question, and hence it will probably be voted to be closed.  You might want to check google, www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/, etc

Comment: It's not even so much that it's the wrong forum - it's more that you haven't outlined a specific question, provided example data or specified what you have tried so far in R.

Comment: @user24534 - if it's minimal data (~10 or so points), sure. If it's 100's or thousands, then just some similar made up data will do.

Comment: What have you done to the question? It is now ridiculously specific and unanswerable?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some ideas to get started, though I would recommend taking a look at the link Ricardo provided in the comments if you want to get started with time series analysis in R. If this is the first thing you are doing with R, you may also benefit from some general reading at a site like: http://www.statmethods.net

I read your data in and saved it to a `data.frame` named `test` using

```
test <- read.table(file="insert.your.file.here",header=TRUE)
```

You can then plot the trends over `time` against one another, using `plot` and `lines` or the `matplot` function which can plot multiple columns at once.

```
matplot(test["time"],test[c("x","y")],type="l")
```

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

Just by eye-balling it, you can see that `y` has increased more than `x` over the period.

If you want to plot the linear trend, you can try using the `lm` function to get the relationship between `time` and the values for each of `x` and `y`.
Like so:

```
lm(y ~ time, data=test), col="red")
lm(x ~ time, data=test), col="black")
```

This will give you the gradient and intercept for the trend. The gradient is the average increase over time. You can add these lines to your plot like so:

```
abline(lm(y ~ time, data=test), col="red"))
abline(lm(x ~ time, data=test), col="black"))
```

[image]

This is a pretty naive analysis though, and you should consider the possibility of seasonal trends in your data or other influences. I suggest you read this: http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html